# osx/c++/glut, adding elapsed time

Tags: c++, macos, glut

I thought I was jumping over a puddle, but have instead fallen into an ocean :/

I'm trying to implement a 5 second timer (don't need more than milliseconds).

My goal:

```
// I start the program in gamestate 0...
{
    if (button_has_been_pressed == 1)
    {
        gamestate = 1;
    }

}

if (gamestate==1)
{
    //wait for 5 seconds and go to gamestate2
    gamestate = 2;

}
```

I've tried the following:

1. GLUT_TIME_ELAPSED measures time from the beginning of my program. I am unable to 'reset' GLUT_TIME_ELAPSED after entering gamestate1. Otherwise, it would work wonderfully.
2. gettimeofday gives me much more resolution than I need. At most, milliseconds would be applicable.

Regardless of my resolution needs, I've tried Song Ho's method:

```
gamestate1_elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
gamestate1_elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms

// add that elapsed time together, and keep track of its total

//r_gamestate1_elapsedTime_total = gamestate1_elapsedTime;
//if (r_gamestate1_elapsedTime_total > 5 seconds) ...
```

However, the gamestate1_elapsedTime appears to have some variability to it. Because the output is seldom consistent. I guess it's b/c gettimeofday employs CPU time(?), and I am artificially clamping this with my fps clamp.

1. I've tried clock() as well, but that also appears to be CPU time - not wall time.

As mentioned above, GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME works well, except that I am unable to reset it midway through my program, and my 5-seconds is no longer dependent upon my initial button click.

I would deeply appreciate even a nudge in the right direction, if you could lend some advice. Thank you very much in advance.

-kropcke

Comment: gettimeofday is wall clock, not CPU time. Unless someone adjusts the system time or time zone, it's monotonic, and pretty precise. Describe the "variability" you're seeing if you want help with it. But anyway, it seems like there's an obvious solution with GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME, so I'll just write that up.

Comment: Also, the value is GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME, not GLUT_TIME_ELAPSED, which means that clearly the code you're posting isn't the same as the code you've tried. See http://sscce.org/ for what you should be posting.

Comment: Finally, do you really want to actually "wait for 5 seconds" (blocking the whole app and spinning at 100% CPU?), or just kick off a timer that does something in 5 seconds? For the latter, `glutTimerFunc(5000, functionThatSetsGameStateTo2, 0)` is the obvious answer.

Comment: I see - I guess I thought wrong about gettimeofday - thank you for the clarification. The variability I was seeing was when I was calculating my total time passed. I was keeping track of milliseconds, and the output didn't appear to tick at the same rate as a wallclock. Sorry about not copying in the same code I was trying - I have been iterating so much that what I had in front of me was no longer applicable to what I was trying to describe. It's clear to me now that this is bad form. My apologies. I've clamped my FPS artificially, so I don't mind spinning the constrained app. Out of chars :/

Comment: I will try the glutTimerFunc as well - thank you again for your answer below - I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "reset" GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME, you just need to copy it somewhere that you can use as an offset. For example:

```
int timeAtReset = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

// I start the program in gamestate 0...
{
    if (button_has_been_pressed == 1)
    {
        gamestate = 1;
        timeAtReset = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    }

}

if (gamestate==1)
{
    int timeSinceReset = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - timeAtReset;
    // use timeSinceReset, instead of glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME), to
    // wait for 5 seconds and go to gamestate2
    gamestate = 2;

}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much abarnert. I have tried offsetting it before, but never as part if the 'if' statement that sets the gamestate to 1. Your methid is very clear to me now. Thank you again so much.